# Why do the values change after leaving the function and why do I get a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I have this homework for my C++ class. I have to implement a list class, where I can add from the front or the back. I have implemented it, but there is a big problem.

collectiontest.cpp

```
#include "list.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "--- Test List ---" << std::endl;
    List<int> l;
    std::cout << l;
    l.add(2);
    l.add_front(3);
    l.add(1);
    std::cout << l;

    std::cout << "remove_front: " << l.remove_front() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "remove_front: " << l.remove_front() << std::endl;
    l.add(5);
    std::cout << l;
    std::cout << "Contains 5? " << l.contains(5) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "remove_back: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << l.remove() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "remove_back: " << l.remove() << std::endl;
    std::cout << l;
return 0;
}
```

list.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "collection.hpp"
#include "node.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class List : public Collection<T> {


private:
    Node<T>* first;
    Node<T>* last;

public:

   

    ~List() {
        if (first != nullptr) {

        }

    }

    void add_front(T value) {

        if (first == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "First element front" << std::endl;
            Node<T> temp(value, nullptr, nullptr);

            first = &temp;
            last = &temp;

        }
        else {

            if (first == last) {

                std::cout << "First and last are same! front-> " << first << "-" << last << std::endl;

                Node<T> temp(value, last, nullptr);
                last->previous = &temp;
                first = &temp;
                std::cout << first << "-" << last << std::endl;

            }
            else {

                Node<T> temp(value, first, nullptr);
                first->previous = &temp;
                first = &temp;


            }



        }

    }

    void add(T value) override {
        std::cout << "LOL" << std::endl;

        if (first == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "First element add" << std::endl;
            Node<T> temp(value, nullptr, nullptr);

            first = &temp;
            last = first;
            std::cout << "end of add first item" << std::endl;
        }
        else {

            if (first == last) {

                std::cout << "First and last are same! add-> " << first << "-" << last << std::endl;
                Node<T> temp(value, nullptr, first);
                first->next = &temp;
                last = &temp;
            }
            else {

                Node<T> temp(value, nullptr, last);
                last->next = &temp;
                last = &temp;


            }




        }



    }

    T remove_front() {

        if (first != nullptr) {
            T te = first->content;
            Node<T>* temp = first;

            first = first->next;

            return te;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    T remove() override {

        if (last != nullptr) {
            Node<T>* temp = last;
            T te = last->content;
            last = last->previous;
            last->next = nullptr;


            return te;
        }

        return NULL;

    }

    bool isEmpty() override {


        return (first == nullptr);

    }

    bool contains(T value) override {

        Node<T>* temp = first;

        while (temp != nullptr) {

            if (temp->content == value) return true;
            temp = temp->next;

        }

        return false;

    }

    void clear() override {

        Node<T>* temp = first->next;

        while (temp != nullptr) {


            first = temp;
            temp = temp->next;


        }

    }

    int getSize() override {
        int counter = 0;
        Node<T>* temp = first;

        while (temp != nullptr) {

            counter++;
            temp = temp->next;
        }


        return counter;

    }

    Node<int>* getFirst() const {
        return first;
    }
    Node<int>* getLast() const {
        return last;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const List<int>& l);


};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const List<int>& l) {
    std::cout << "Output called" << std::endl;
    Node<int>* temp = l.getLast();



    while (temp != nullptr) {

        std::cout << "Schleife betreten" << std::endl;
        stream << temp->content << " ";





        temp = temp->previous;


    }

    stream << std::endl;

    return stream;
}
```

collection.hpp

```
#pragma once
template <typename T>
class Collection {

    virtual void add(T value) = 0;
    virtual int remove() = 0;
    virtual bool isEmpty() = 0;
    virtual bool contains(T obj) = 0;
    virtual void clear() = 0;
    virtual int getSize() = 0;



};
```

node.hpp

```
#pragma once
template <typename T>
class Node {



public:
    Node<T>* next;
    Node<T>* previous;
    T content;

    Node(T value, Node<T>* next, Node<T>* previous) {

        content = value;
        this->next = next;
        this->previous = previous;



    }

    ~Node() {

    }



};
```

I have looked over it several times, but I get the same error.

I debugged my program with Visual Studio, and what happens is `collectortest.cpp` creates the list and adds the first value with the `add()` function. In the debugger, I see how the `temp` node is created, how `first` is set to the address of `temp`, and how `last` is set to the same address. So, when we reach the line where "end of add first item" is supposed to be printed to the console, the variables changes, why??

You can see in this image how the variables all have appropriate values:

Before the output:

[image]

But then, when I leave the breakpoint I set at "end of add first item", this happens:

After the output:

[image]

There must be something I don't see, because this makes literally no sense. I have looked everywhere, maybe it is just something really dumb, but I am really at my limits here.

Can one of you help and explain what the problem is?

I tried to execute my program and create the nodes appropriately, but I get a strange error in my memory.

Comment: `Node<T> temp(value, nullptr, nullptr); first = &temp;`  You're using a pointer to something that is allocated on the stack and will be destroyed/invalid when it goes out of scope whether you have taken note of the address it used to be at or not.

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense, thats a really dumb mistake on my side. But how can I do it differently? Do I need to store the Nodes somewhere for them to not be deleted? Which memory addresses are deleted if not in use? @Wyck

Comment: In `T remove() override` you check if `last != nullptr` before extracting a `T` and returning it. That's fine, but if `last == nullptr` you return `NULL`. Don't. Throw an exception. Not all `T`s can be constructed from `NULL`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thats not where I was stuck, but thank you that also makes a lot of sense, the task was very unspecific so I just put the return NULL as a placeholder, but that could be dangerous

Comment: For the problem @Wyck mentioned, you need to allocate and release memory dynamically using `new`/`delete`.

Comment: `Node<T> temp(value, nullptr, nullptr); first = &temp;` is one of the increasingly rare times you want to use `new`. `first = new Node<T>(value, nullptr, nullptr);`

Comment: @Kunait First, you should remove the excess space between lines of your code.  Second, If `T` is a `std::string`, you cannot return NULL.  Instead, just return a default constructed T, i.e. `return {};`

Comment: Thank you all so much, that makes sense I just read how new works in C++ and that is what I needed. It was difficult to stop using new as someone who learned Java first, but now I need it :)

Comment: [Here's a link to a presentation by Herb Sutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE) on using smart pointers. I'm not a fan of using them in a general-purpose linked list because they turn what could be iterative destruction logic into a potentially stack-popping recursion, but it's good stuff to know.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your comment, the spaces are because I deleted debug stuff and forgot to clean it up thank you for the reminder, the second problem is already solved because TedLyngmo told me the same thing, again thanks

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks I will look into it, I am pretty new into C++ so there is still a lot to learn.

Comment: I'm not new and there's still a lot for me to learn. Very deep language, C++.

Comment: @Kunait -- Yes, it was suspicious that your code was avoiding using `new`, as you can't really build a linked list data structure in C++ (you can, but it isn't easy) without dynamic allocation.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah i believe you, its really a lot

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah now it all makes sense, again thank you all very much i can now close this question

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

[From @Wyck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75165209/#comment132640460_75165209):

> ```
> Node<T> temp(value, nullptr, nullptr);
> first = &temp;
> ```
>
> You're using a pointer to something that is allocated on the stack and will be destroyed/invalid when it goes out of scope whether you have taken note of the address it used to be at or not.

[From @user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75165209/#comment132640610_75165209):

> ```
> Node<T> temp(value, nullptr, nullptr);
> first = &temp;
> ```
>
> is one of the increasingly rare times you want to use `new`.
>
> ```
> first = new Node<T>(value, nullptr, nullptr);
> ```

[From @TedLyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75165209/#comment132640606_75165209):

> For the problem @Wyck mentioned, you need to allocate and release memory dynamically using `new`/`delete`.

These were the answers posted as comments to the question. My `Node`s always got destroyed because they were out of scope. I needed to use `new` so they got stored in the heap and weren't automatically destroyed if they went out of scope.

Edit: I can't choose my own answer as correct for 2 days, so the question sadly stays open.